# How to create a wrapper for jQuery's css() method that uses native JavaScript functions instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to transition from jQuery to vanilla JavaScript and I'm looking for a way to replace jQuery's css() method with a native JavaScript alternative. After some research, I've found that there are a few native JavaScript functions such as style.setProperty() and element.style that can be used instead of jQuery's method.

To make the transition easier, I'm thinking of creating a wrapper function for jQuery's css() method that will call these native functions instead. Here's a draft of what I have so far:

```
// Define the css2() method
$.fn.css2 = function(property, value) {
  // If only one argument is provided and it's an object, set multiple properties
  if (arguments.length === 1 && typeof property === 'object') {
    // Loop through all elements in the jQuery object
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      // Set each property-value pair using native JS
      for (var prop in property) {
        // Map camelCase CSS property names to hyphen-separated names
        var hyphenatedProp = prop.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2').toLowerCase();
        this[i].style[hyphenatedProp] = property[prop];
      }
    }
    // Return the jQuery object for chaining
    return this;
  }
  
  // Map camelCase CSS property names to hyphen-separated names
  var hyphenatedProperty = property.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2').toLowerCase();

  // Loop through all elements in the jQuery object
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    // Set the style property using native JS
    this[i].style[hyphenatedProperty] = value;
  }

  // Return the jQuery object for chaining
  return this;
};
```

Is this the right approach? Are there any potential issues or edge cases that I should be aware of? Any suggestions or feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I have created and maintain a 'jquery-alike' [library](https://github.com/KooiInc/JQL/). [Here is the `style` method](https://github.com/KooiInc/JQL/blob/9ede105f6dafc013ac594115e1ca260d7a2c8fbf/src/JQLMethods.js#L86) of it, maybe helpful.

Comment: *Is this the right approach?* - where does it end? Wrapper for the verbose document.getEelementById - how about `myplugin("#id")`?   What about a nice easy to use wrapper for the tedium of adding event handlers?   And a myriad of other long winded javascript methods?   *Is this the right approach?* - no, just use jquery.

Comment: *Is this the right approach?* - no, use classes (even over jquery.css).  js class methods aren't too crazy.